# How to fetch the value from multiple html elements in a generic way using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a generic method for fetching the value from multiple html elements.

Example :

```
<div>Test</div>
<select><option>Test</option></select>
<input value="Test" />
```

So the above three are the different html elements, which has a value. Instead of writing three different methods, for fetching the value, is there any way to write a single method and get the value from all.

This is what I have tried:

```
$("div").text();
$("select option:selected").val();
$('input').val();
```

Comment: `$('select option:selected, intput').val();` for example. May be you'd better write helper function for that?

Comment: "different html elements, which have a value" - you need to get your definitions straight

Answer (score 1):

Add classes to the objects:

```
<div class="myObjectClass">Test</div>
<select class="myObjectClass"><option>Test</option></select>
<input class="myObjectClass" value="Test" />
```

Then use javascript (jQuery) to loop them:

```
$(".myObjectClass").each(function(){
//do something
});
```

Comment: I can prefer the loop, but the thing is I wont get to know which element I will get, because the DOM structure will come from different vendors. And I dont have any unique class to identify.

Comment: Then use $('*'); to get ALL DOM-objects. Will be a mess though.

Answer (score 0):

In pure JavaScript:

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/9qxs2cty/

```js
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('*')).map(function (i) {
  if (i.value !== "undefined") {
    console.log(i.value);
  } else {
    console.log(i.textContent);
  }
});
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
<select>
  <option>Test</option>
</select>
<input value="Test" />
```

I don't know your situtation, but you probably want to at least limit that to `document.body`:

```js
[].slice.call(document.body.getElementsByTagName('*')).map(function(i) {
  if (i.value !== "undefined") {
    console.log(i.value);
  } else {
    console.log(i.textContent);
  }
});
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
<select>
  <option>Test</option>
</select>
<input value="Test" />
```